# How to scrape an autocomplete?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, autocomplete

I was trying to scrape the autocomplete of a website. Basically, I was trying to get every entry in their autocomplete. The first thing that came to my mind was writing a recursive **scraper**, so it checks for all combinations - aa,aaa,aaab, etc. (For all 26 alphabets). But this seems incredibly inefficient. My second approach was to scrape some of their documents, compute Tf-IDF and extract the keywords. This gave some good results, but I am pretty sure I couldn't cover their entire database. Are there any other methods? What do you'll suggest?

Regards,

Comment: I Can't understand your problem. Please be brief. What is autocomplete?

Comment: I want to scrape the autocomplete of a website. The entire database. Autocomplete - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocomplete

Comment: You mean the number of pages inside a website???

Comment: Please read the question. It is clear.

Comment: Why you didn't tried recursion  like aa,aaa,aaab? I have that algorith so you can easily try this...

Comment: Imagine how much time it takes. Just with n=7 for all alphabets you get more than 10mil combinations.

Comment: Not really. 'qq' for example will be empty so you stop there. You only keep going when you think the results were limited.

Comment: Can you post a link to the page you are trying to scrap? We might be able to find a better way of doing it. They could have a page with all the data, or a javascript function that returns more info.

Comment: @pguardiario Aah, yes that could be an approach. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @Rusty Robot here is the page - https://indiankanoon.org/. Currently I was scraping based on the API call the site was making. Would love to know if there are alternatives

Comment: So you start with "aaa" - it gives 5 results so you continue to "aaaa" which gives 2, so you stop there and move on to "aaab". just keep doing that recursively.

Comment: I'll try it out!

Comment: @RustyRobot Did you check it out?

Comment: Didn't see your last comment. I'll have a look tomorrow morning. ~11 hours.

Answer (score 0):

For the page: `https://indiankanoon.org/`

When you type something into the search box it makes a request to `https://indiankanoon.org/qsuggest/?term=` which brings back the autocomplete information. Rather than attempting to scrape `https://indiankanoon.org/` I would instead scrape the `qsuggest` page instead.

https://indiankanoon.org/qsuggest/?term=aaa

I should mention that the `qsuggest` page only returns results for terms with 3 or more letters. Scraping all 3 letter combinations that will be over 17000 requests. If you make a request every 5 seconds, it will take a little more than 60 days to get all the information, provided the site doesn't block you first. They do have an API listed on the website, maybe that can help.

Comment: Yes, I am currently scraping qsuggest. As you said, a recursive scrapper takes a looot of time. I guess you can't scrape it everything:(